# Using mutate and slice_max in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, slice

I have the following dataframe:

```
df=data.frame(defect= 
                        c("defect1","defect2","defect3","defect4","defect5","defect6","defect7",
                          "defect8","defect9","defect10","defect11","defect12","defect13"),
                      num=c(1,2,5,10,20,25,35,45,60,70,3,4,5))
```

and I want to use mutate and slice_max to get the top 5 and top 10 defects but this doesn't work:

```
df%>%
  summarise(Defect_list_top_5=paste0(slice_max(num,n=5)," ",num, collapse="|"),
            Defect_list_top_10=paste0(slice_max(num,n=5)," ",num, collapse="|"))
```

I know how to do it this way and the final represents what I expect the output to be:

```
 x=df%>%
  slice_max(num,n=5)%>%
  summarise(Defect_list_top_5=paste0(defect," ",num, collapse = "|"))
  
y=df%>%
  slice_max(num,n=10)%>%
  summarise(Defect_list_top_10=paste0(defect," ",num, collapse = "|"))

final=cbind(x,y)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to force something do what it cannot do? Seems you already have a solution of what you want

Comment: I want to find a better solution for it, I don't think what I'm doing is the best method to do it

Comment: How do you define *better*. Because you are trying to call `slice_max` within `summary` which you should not. but if you want you can still make it work yet it will not be bettwer but rather worse

Comment: is there any other way to do it? it doesn't necessarily have to be this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>%
    slice_max(num, n = 10) %>%
    summarise(top_5 = paste(defect[1:5],collapse = "|"),
                        top_10 = paste(defect, collapse = "|"))
```

Answer (score 1):

One result has 10 rows, the other has 5 rows. Then you are converting each result to a single text vector so they can be put into a data frame, which does not seem to be the appropriate data structure for your result.

What you are looking for is a `list`:

```
x = df %>%
slice_max(num, n=5)

y = df %>%
  slice_max(num, n=10)

final = list("Top 5" = x, "Top 10" = y)
final
```